# EventBus event between two fragments not fired

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, event-bus

**Problem:** I am using `EventBus` by [greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to pass some events. 
It is working for me unfortunately for the scenario of passing data between two `fragments` it does not. So the event does not get fired.

**Question:** Do I misunderstand the concept? Or is there a mistake in my code?

**Note:** Both Fragments exist at the time of sending the event. One `fragment` is the parent and the other one the child to display details.

detail fragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
(...)

refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
EventBus.getDefault().post(new IntentRefresh());
            }
        });
(...)

}
```

EventBus class:

```
public class IntentRefresh {

    public IntentRefresh (){}

    public void refreshParent() {

    }

}
```

parent fragment:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void updateList(IntentRefresh intentRefresh) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LUEEEEPT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Are both fragments resumed at the same time? Make sure the parent fragment is not paused which will unsubscribe it from the bus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fragment lifecycle is quite a bit more complicated than the Activity lifecycle. I would guess that your onResume() isn't being called how you think it is. I would recommend moving your registering and un registering to the onAttach() and onDetach() methods.

Answer (score 0):

I use @CaseyB's answer. its working for me perfectly.Like below

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(CallbackModel event) {

}
```